# Sorting associative array with multiple conditions

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a table called "parents_kids", it has three columns known as:

```
id  Guardian    kids
1   Greg        1
2   Gary        3
3   Aaron       2
4   Farb        3
5   REX         1
6   Fred        2
```

In the following code I get it into array and print it:

```
$exc = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID,Guardian,kids from current_state");
        $exc->execute();
            while($finalResult = $exc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
             {
                        $tables[] = $finalResult;
             }
var_dump($tables);
```

once i got this into an array, **i sorted it in a custom order where 
first the guardians with 2 kids, then with 1 kid and who has 3**

```
ID    Guardian  kids
3     Aaron     2
6     Fred      2
1     Greg      1
5     REX       1
4     Farb      3
2     Gary      3
```

Now my requirement is to order this rest of the array according to its ID to descending order,

for example just like this

```
ID    Guardian  kids
6     Fred      2
3     Aaron     2
5     REX       1
1     Greg      1
4     Farb      3
2     Gary      3
```

i tried this many times but its dint work, the code i used to sort the first requirement is as follows

```
$order = array("2", "1", "3");

usort($tables, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a['kids'], $order);
    $pos_b = array_search($b['kids'], $order);
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});
```

**can anybody help me to fullfil my second requirement which is sort the array by ID to descending order**

This is how the array looks like

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'ID' => string '3' (length=1)
      'Guardian' => string 'Aaron' (length=5)
      'kids' => string '2' (length=1)

array (size=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'ID' => string '6' (length=1)
      'Guardian' => string 'FRED' (length=4)
      'kids' => string '2' (length=1)
```

etc

**P.S doing it from the table is not going to work, because im using a loop above the code which makes it impossible to do it from the SQL, can anybody tell me a way to do it from the php**

Comment: Can you edit your post and add how the array looks like?

Comment: Why not just put an ORDER BY on your query and have the SQL server return the data in the order you want?

Comment: Theres a bigger code behind this, records get added one by one using the sql, therefore the ORDER BY does not apply to it, thats why i have got it into array and sorting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two primary issues.

1. You were using `status` as the first key when it should have been `kids` based on your description.
2. You need to check whether the first subtraction was zero, and if so, compare the id values.

Here is a working solution.

```
$order = array("2", "1", "3");

usort($tables, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a['kids'], $order);
    $pos_b = array_search($b['kids'], $order);
    $result =  $pos_a - $pos_b;
    if ($result != 0) return $result;

    return intval($b['ID']) - intval($a['ID']);
});

var_dump($tables);
```

Comment: @ShoGumLew, If this does not work you'll have to edit your example, since I tested on your example. :)

Comment: no need :D this wokrs like a charm... btw can you tell me somewhere a tute or something to practice these type of sorting with "use" keyword

Comment: @ShoGumLew, I don't know any sites that give comparator specific practice, but if you want to improve your algorithms you can look on Topcoder.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it should help:

```
select ID,Guardian,kids
from current_state
order by case WHEN kids = 2 then 1
              WHEN kids = 1 then 2
              WHEN kids = 3 then 3
              ELSE kids END ASC
, ID desc
```